# Smarty concat/foreach assignment

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I have a main array:

```
$occupations = ['hs','uni','parent'];
```

and other multiple array of type

```
$columns_hs;$columns_uni;
```

etc.
I want to foreach through the "$occupations" array and then foreach through the other arrays but cant seem to get the right syntax.
Here is my code:

```
{foreach from=$occupations item=ov key=ok}
    {foreach from=$columns_`$ov`}
        do something
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

I am using smarty 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own varible with [assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

Declare one array colums

```
$colums = array(
 'hs' => [1,2,3,4],
 'uni' => [5,6,7,8]
);
```

and your code in foreach is

```
{foreach from=$occupations item=ov key=ok}
    {foreach from=$columns[$ov]}
        do something
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```